# Recover disappeared files on NTFS HD after CHKDSK

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ntfs, data-recovery, file-recovery

On my computer with Win7, after only one execution of CHKDSK, all files disappear on my secondary HD (around 500Gb of very important data). I read the CHKDSK logfile and it has found many mistakes on the HD including on the MFT. Now on windows or linux, I see no file on the HD...

I have tried TestDisk software for finding deleted files but no file can be recovered. I have tried many other software (but non free) and I can see some disappeared files...

I have tried to repair the MFT using TestDisk but it said that MFT and MFT mirror are bad. Do you have any idea to repair the MFT using an other technique or another software? If not, is it possible to recover the files AND the filetree? With which technique?

I am very surprised of this unexpected and unacceptable behaviour of CHKDSK...

---

Status of the HD BEFORE: 1 NTFS partition with around 500gb of files

Status of the HD AFTER: 1 NTFS partition with 0 file...

---

Tools I have if needed:

- one Linux/Win7 computer
- MacBook
- only a small 500gb external drive (if necessary I will buy a new 2To HD)

Comment: Try this utility: http://www.easeus.com/data-recovery-software/.

Comment: You can try R-Studio  demo version to see if it can find anything.

Comment: I have used this service before when test disk and other utilities could not recover the mft, they are the lowest cost but very reputable, saved my bacon and about 1.5tb of data....http://www.lowcostrecovery.com/

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have two options -- pay for a data recovery service (typical 2014 cost $100 to $200 for the attempt, no guarantee you get anything back), or obtain and learn to use a "forensic file recovery" package.  I've used one of those, several years ago, to recover data from a hard disk with head impact damage (computer fell about 1.5 meters on concrete, while powered off); I didn't get much back, but did recover a couple years worth of e-mail.

Forensic file recovery is a slow process (expect to take overnight or longer, possibly multiple days running continuously, on a 500 GB drive -- likely worse through USB), but it's the kind of process used to recover data that's been *overwritten*, and over time can usually recover any data that isn't on a physically damaged sector.  I'm not up to date on this (I don't do file recovery professionally and it's been several years since I'd needed it), so I can't give you package names, but if you search "forensic file recovery" you should find what you need, and last time I needed it, it was available as freeware.  Fortunately, you don't care about chain of evidence, but just about getting your data back; that will simplify your process compared to finding information that will stand up in court.

Answer (score 0):

"We should backup our important files to something else like shared server, LAN, cloud storage not limit on the disk.

As long as the data isn't overwritten, your files should be still in disk. As Maudam said, try EaseUS Data Recovery. "

Comment: What is your experience with the tool? Why should it be used?

Comment: I think the first step will be the best for the moment. I will buy a new HD and make a copy of my 1Tb HD using `ddrescue` command.